# measuring the time to load a page - Python

Tags: python

I'm using [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html), so I can open a html to an performance test I'm currently doing.
This small piece of code is the begin of the automation. The goal of the function `perf_measure` is to return how long took to load the page in `url` entirely.

```
import webbrowser

def perf_measure(url=""):

    try:
        webbrowser.open(url)

    except webbrowser.Error, e:
        print "It couldn't open the url: ", url

url = "www.google.com"
open_browser(url)
```

How can I accomplish that? I just need the value, in seconds, like:

```
www.google.com  Total time to load page in (secs): 2.641
```

Comment: `webbrowser.open` opens your Firefox/Chrome/smth. It does not load the page in Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you need to use the web browser? As in do you need to view the result?

Otherwise you could do this.

```
import urllib2
from time import time

stream = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-420.exe')
start_time = time()
output = stream.read()
end_time = time()
stream.close()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

If you want a more human-readable result you can use [round](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round).

```
print(round(end_time-start_time, 3))
```

**Output**

```
0.865000009537 # Without Round
0.865          # With Round
```

Comment: Anderson, so do I do to format `end_time-start_time` in seconds nicely?

Comment: I had done that ... the result looks like `5.50746917725e-05` so I wanted to leave it in seconds, nicely, like `2.05`

Comment: I get `1.18000006676` when downloading a 1mb file.

Comment: Try running my example. It should give you around 1s depending on your bandwidth.

Comment: if anyone is meeting with an error for urllib2, try this instead: `from urllib.request import urlopen`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to time the page load (including all of the resources it loads, rendering time etc.) in a real browser you can use [Selenium Webdriver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html). This will open your browser of choice, load the URL and then extract timings:

```py
from selenium import webdriver


def time_url(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)

    # Use the browser Navigation Timing API to get some numbers:
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API
    navigation_start = driver.execute_script(
        "return window.performance.timing.navigationStart")
    dom_complete = driver.execute_script(
        "return window.performance.timing.domComplete")
    total_time = dom_complete - navigation_start

    print(f"Time {total_time}ms")


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    url = "https://httpbin.org/delay/"
    time_url(driver, url + '1')
    time_url(driver, url + '2')

finally:
    driver.close()
```

There are many [other metrics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming) you can load if you want to know the render-time separately from the loading time etc.

Answer (score 3):

A fancy way using a decorator

```
import time

def time_it(func):
    def wrapper(*arg,**kw):
        t1 = time.time()
        res = func(*arg,**kw)
        t2 = time.time()
        return (t2-t1),res,func.func_name
    return wrapper

@time_it
def perf_measure(url=""):
    #w hatever you want
    pass
```

Comment: Decorators are for sure one of my favorite Python features. :)