# Get current page load time setting Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to get page load timeout for current driver object to be able to make something like this:

```
old_timeout = <get somehow current page load timeout value from self.driver>
new_timeout = 100
self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(new_timeout)
self.driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(old_timeout)
```

In other words, I just want to get current timeout setting, change it to new one, do something and after that restore setting how it was. The only thing in this chain I don't know how to do - is to get current timeout setting.

I don't want to measure how long will it take to load page.

The idea is to change this setting for 1-time request and return it back how it was.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you have similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202548/measuring-the-time-to-load-a-page-python

Comment: Unfortunately, not similar. I don't want to know how long will it take to load the page (and measure it.). I just want to get current timeout setting, change it to new one, do something and after that restore setting how it was. The only thing in this chain I don't know how to do - is to get current timeout setting.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to get the current timeout settings from the driver. You have two options:

- If you initialize the driver in the same class keep the timeout in variable.
- Create temporary driver and work with it

  ```
  temp_driver = self.driver
  temp_driver.set_page_load_timeout(100)
  temp_driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
  ```